# Spring Integration: Programmatically send request to outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to send requests to a web service endpoint (also configured using integration) using data generated by integration elements. There is a part in my workflow which I have to program myself. Usually I create a gateway object/interface, Autowire and use it to send/receive data from the integration workflow. I would like to do something similar but instead of using the generic gateway I would like to use the web service outbound gateway. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed already the *first class citizen* is `MessageChannel` and the logic in the integration flow is based on the `Message` sending from one endpoint to another over those `MessageChannel`s.

So, as you guess right now to send a request to the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` you should use its `request-channel` and send a `Message<?>` object to it. For this purpose the Framework provides for you a `MessagingTemplate` which you can use from you own code bypassing the `gateway` abstraction. And there is a convenient method on the matter - `convertAndSend()`. Also pay attention to the `MessageBuilder` utility to simplify your messaging life.